# Edit Mysql table with same Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have sql table like this :

```
NIP | Nama | Keahlian
1      A        X
1      A        Y
1      A        Z
2      B        R
2      B        S
2      B        T
```

I want to edit Column `keahlian` to be like this :
`

```
NIP | Nama | Keahlian
1      A        X
1      A        Y
1      A        W
2      B        R
2      B        S
2      B        T
```

But currently I cannot make it because when I edit the particular record, other record with the same `NIP` also changed. So, how to fix that?

Comment: well that is why `PRIMARY_KEY` exist. you should have that in your table. But you can still update particular row using `.. WHERE NIP = ? AND Nama= ? AND Keahlian = ? `

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Primary key to your table so that records can be uniquely identified.
Unless you always know that the value of NIP, Nama and Keahlian combined is unique, then you can do:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Keahlian='W' WHERE NIP = 1 and Nama = 'A' and Keahlian = 'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this SQL query and change the tablename to your table name:

```
UPDATE  tablename SET  `Keahlian` ='W',
WHERE NIP=1 AND Nama='A' AND `Keahlian`='Z'
```

this way you will only update the wanted row

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE  table_name set  Keahlian ='W', WHERE Keahlian='Z'.
```

it will work fine, if the Keahlian is primary key.